# How to know the next point in the arc if we know the radius coordinate, first point on arc and angle of change between first and next point?

Tags: circles

How to know the next point in the arc if we know the radius coordinate, first point on arc and angle of change between first and next point ?

Let's suppose we have point first as $(1117, 453)$, the radius coordinates as $(720, 853)$ and angle of change between the next point and first point is $3.6^\circ$.

What will be the coordinates of next point on the arc ?

I have calculated the radius with the formula attached formula to find the length between two points The radius I got is approx $563$.

I am expecting the formula to find the next point in the arc with $3.6^\circ$ change in clockwise direction.